# Optimize SQL query Select on Select Case

Tags: sql-server

I was looking for some threads in here that mention optimization in queries, but i couldn't resolve my problem.

I need to perform a query in SQL Server that involve using a select case on my primary select, this is the description of the main table:

WS:

```
| Oid | model_code | product_code | year |
```

In my query, I need to select all of this columns plus an extra column that compares to another table if by some criteria the values from my main table exist on my other table, let me explain my other table and then I explain what i mean by this.

TA:

```
| Oid | model_code | product_code | year |
```

Both tables have matching columns, so for example, if on my table WS I have this result:

```
| Oid | model_code | product_code | year |
|  1  |      13    |     123      | 2018 |
```

And on my TA table I have this:

```
| Oid | model_code | product_code | year |
|  1  |      25    |     134      | 2016 |
|  2  |      13    |     123      | 2018 |
|  3  |      67    |     582      | 2017 |
```

I need to print an "Exist" result on that row because the row on my main table match exactly with this 3 column values.

So my query on that row should print something like this:

```
| model_code | product_code | year | Exist |
|      13    |     123      | 2018 |  Yes  |
```

The query I was trying to use to make this happen, was this:

```
SELECT 
    WS.Oid, WS.model_code, WS.product_code, Ws.year,
    (SELECT   
         CASE   
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TA 
                         WHERE TA.model_code = Ws.model_code 
                           AND TA.product_code = Ws.product_code 
                           AND TA.[Year] = Ws.[Year]) 
               THEN 'Yes'   
               ELSE 'No'   
         END) as 'Exist'
FROM 
    Ws
```

And it works, the problem is that on my real tables there are more columns and more rows (about 960,000) and for example, a query around 50,000 elements (using this query) takes more than a minute, and the same query with same elements but without the select case, takes about 2 seconds, so the difference is **immense**.

I'm sure that a more viable way to achieve this exist, in less time, but I don't know how. any recommendations?

Comment: can you share explain plan please? this is probably an indexing issue. the columns of the  TA table is needed to be properly indexed

Comment: I think you're looking for `JOIN TA ta ON ta.model_code = ws.model_code AND ta.product_code = ws.product_code AND ta.year = ws.year`

Comment: I think they need an `OUTER JOIN` because they want to display all of the records and indicate whether or not there's a matching record in the other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless already there, an index on `ta (model_code, product_code, year)` might help.

```
CREATE INDEX ta_model_code_product_code_year
             ON ta (model_code,
                    product_code,
                    year);
```

Though chances are that the optimizer already rewrites your query in such a way, another thing you could try is to (explicitly) rewrite the query using a left join. I assume `oid` is `NOT NULL` in `ta`.

```
SELECT ws.oid,
       ws.model_code,
       ws.product_code,
       ws.year,
       CASE
         WHEN ta.oid IS NULL THEN
           'No'
         ELSE
           'Yes'
       END exist
       FROM ws
            LEFT JOIN ta
                      ON ta.model_code = ws.model_code
                         AND ta.product_code = ws.product_code
                         AND ta.year = ws.year;
```

With that you want the index from above and maybe try one one `ws (model_code, product_code, year)` too.

```
CREATE INDEX ws_model_code_product_code_year
             ON ws (model_code,
                    product_code,
                    year);
```

You might also want to play with the order of the columns in the indexes. If for a column more distinct values exist in `ta`, put it before a column where fewer distinct values exist in `ta`. But keep the order in both indexes identical, i.e. if you shift a column in the index on `ta` also move it in the index on `ws` the same way.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is join the two tables together, instead of looking for a matching record for each record.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    WS.model_code, WS.product_code, Ws.year,
        SELECT CASE
            WHEN TA.OID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END As 'Exist'
FROM WS LEFT OUTER JOIN TA ON
    TA.model_code = Ws.model_code 
         AND TA.product_code = Ws.product_code 
         AND TA.[Year] = Ws.[Year]
```

That will print all of the records from the WS table, and if there's a matching record in the TA table, the 'Exist' column will say 'Yes', otherwise it will say 'No'.

This uses one query to do everything.  Your original approach would do a completely separate sub-query to check the TA table, and that is creating your performance issue.

You may also want to look at putting indexes on these 3 fields in each table to make the matching go even faster.